# Need to improve ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to look in a string for the same pattern twice. Only when joined with "and" but I can't seem to pull the second match correctly

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :040 > text
 => "start a week and 2 days" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :041 > text.scan /[a\d] weeks?|months?|years? and [a\d] weeks?|months?|days?/
 => ["a week", "days"]
```

I don't understand why the second match is "days" and not "2 days"

If I swap the "a" and "2" then the second match still excludes that character.

Any help massively appreciated!

---

To clarify my algorithm is going to be

if string contains x units and y units then
  do something to x units
  do something to y units
end

---

I've also tried

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :054 > text.scan /[a|\d] (weeks?|months?|years?) and [a|\d] (weeks?|months?|days?)/
 => [["week", "days"]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :055 > text.scan /([a|\d] weeks?|months?|years?) and ([a|\d] weeks?|months?|days?)/
 => []
```

---

As an experiment I tried simplifying the pattern with no success at improvement

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :059 > text = "2 weeks and a day"
 => "2 weeks and a day" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :060 > text.scan /[a|\d] weeks?|months?|years?|days?/
 => ["2 weeks", "day"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :061 > text = "a week and 2 days"
 => "a week and 2 days" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :062 > text.scan /[a|\d] weeks?|months?|years?|days?/
 => ["a week", "days"]
```

---

Thanks to all who contributed...

```
/([a\d] years?|[a\d] months?|[a\d] weeks?) and ([a\d] days?|[a\d] weeks?|[a\d] months?)/
```

matches my requirements but I'd definitely be interested to know if it could be reduced in size...

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :077 > text = "2 weeks and a day"
 => "2 weeks and a day" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :078 > text.scan /([a\d] years?|[a\d] months?|[a\d] weeks?) and ([a\d] days?|[a\d] weeks?|[a\d] months?)/
 => [["2 weeks", "a day"]] 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :079 > text = "2 weeks 2 days"
 => "2 weeks 2 days" 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :080 > text.scan /([a\d] years?|[a\d] months?|[a\d] weeks?) teand ([a\d] days?|[a\d] weeks?|[a\d] months?)/
 => []
```

Comment: The character class `[a|\d]` matches any character that is a literal `a`, a literal `|`, or a digit. Inside character classes you do not use the `|` for alternation. Outside of character classes, you need to specify at what level to alternate using parenthesis. `/this an|and that/` matches `"this an"` or `"and that"`, while `/this (?:an|and) that/` matches `"this an that"` or `"this and that"`.

Comment: I'm very confused that my answer was deleted and shifted into the question because "This is a question and answer site, not a newsgroup or discussion forum. It works by someone asking a question, and then people can post answers to the question by typing into the "Your Answer" area. Your post is not an answer to the question asked (even if you're the one who asked it), and should not appear as one." It definitely is the answer - the contributions of those below and Phrogz above helped me zero in on the problem...

Comment: You asked a question. You got 1-2 answers that (as far as I can tell) correctly and fully answered your question. The appropriate step at this point is to mark one of those answers as accepted. If you have a different question, post it as a new question. Re-posting the correct answer as your own answer and asking a new question is not the correct way to continue the discussion. (This is not a matter of strict policy adherence, but rather ensuring that the site is full of concrete QA that can help others.) If you have only a minor followup question, you can post it as a comment and hope..

Comment: You can reduce the amount of code (but not the regex) like this: `unit = "(a|\\d+) (year|month|week)s?"; text.scan(/#{unit} and #{unit}/).flatten #=> ["2", "week", "a", "day"]`; as an added bonus, moving the `s` out of the capturing group normalizes your results (so you don't have to handle both "week" and "weeks".

Comment: None of the answers provided work - although they did help... fire up irb and see if you can match the last example above with them. jtbandes comes closest but his answer still doesn't actually hit the requirement.

Comment: In that case, the appropriate approach would be to comment on the answer(s), pointing out the flaws with each. I only now understand that maybe you wanted this regex: `/((?:a|\d+) (?:week|month|year|day)s?) and ((?:a|\d+) (?:week|month|year|day)s?)/`. Alternatively, if no one answer was right but you did get it, then posting your own answer (without followup question) is appropriate. In the future, I suggest clearly providing a set of input and the exact output you want for each.

Comment: Phrogz, I posted the answer... a mod deleted it and shifted it into the question. Regards clarity - once you know the answer it's easy to be clear but when you aren;t even really sure what the question is... :) You are however spot on with that regex - if you'd like to post it as an answer it definitely improves on mine and I'd happily accept it

Answer (score 3):

```
(a|\d) (weeks?|months?|years?) and (a|\d) (weeks?|months?|days?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put parentheses around your alternation groups: `... (weeks?|months?|years?) ...`

However your regex still has problems because you're matching the whole string and not using groups to get the specific parts. `String#scan` may not be the easiest way to do this. It might just be better to use `text.sub(/^start\s+/,"").split(/\s+and\s+/)`.

You could also check out the [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) gem if you want to parse these into dates.

Comment: Coincidentally I'm doing this because Chronic can't handle the use case of eg "2 weeks and a day from now"

Comment: Ah. I found a post somewhere that suggested splitting at "and", then passing each part to Chronic separately. Have you tried that?